# push notification not receiving when app is closed in xamarin.forms

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.forms

I have implemented push notification in my xamarin.forms app.

I used gsm notification in android and for IOS used plugin.

that works fine when app is in foreground or background.but if i close(kill) app then don't receive notification.

any one have idea about this.

please help.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you added permissions

**iOS:**

info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>voip</string>
<string>fetch</string>
<string>remote notification</string>
</array>
```

**Android:**

**Manifest file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="co.my.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="co.my.packagename.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And once deploy application using release mode then try

Comment: what about android?

Comment: i can test in andorid only now.as i dont have ios device

Comment: It's woking or not?

Comment: In iOS the permission is <string>remote-notification</string> - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uibackgroundmodes